# Is it possible to edit Reports in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, scrum

I want to edit the Velocity Report generated with Visual Studio 2010s scrum template.
How can I edit it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my own issue.
I'm interested in changing the results shown for a Scrum Template report.

1. Open the report in the "Project Portal" (right click on the Team
   project in Visual Studio and select "Show Project Portal".
2. Click on the report, e.g. Velocity.
3. Click the "properties" tab on the top.
4. Click the "Parameters" tab on the left. Some parameters are editable
   here, e.g in my case "DoneName". I'm changing this to "Committed"
   instead of "Done" so that I can see the items marked as committed.
   This parameter can be make editable from the brower ui by selecting
   the "Prompt User" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307361/tfs-2010-scrum-1-0-template-i-want-to-add-more-reports). Also you can try to import the report to SSRS environment and try making the changes there.

You can also consider customizing the report you require based on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730838.aspx).

Hope this helps.